# Permission error trying this backup script

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, backup, tar

I am trying this [Backup Shell Script](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/backup-shellscripts.html) from the server guide. Granted it's for my desktop running Xubuntu 14.04.

The NFS is mounted and accessible. The script has been created and edited with the correct directories I want to back up, and has the following permissions;

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 661 May 25 20:51 prod1backup.sh
```

The error given is; `tar (child): /home/servershare/networkbackup/zach-Ubuntu-TT-1-Sunday.tgz: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

I believe tar does not have permission to create the file, as running a tar by itself outside of the script requires `sudo`.

Any suggestions? I don't know much about scripting, but am trying to pick up bits and pieces.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you following two ways.

First. To modify `/home/servershare/networkbackup` folder's permission.

```
$ sudo chown -R servershare:servershare /home/servershare/networkbackup

$ ./prod1backup.sh
```

Second. To use sudo command directly.

```
$ sudo ./prod1backup.sh
```

I think that `"Permission denied"` is shown, because it folder's owner is not current user.